# How to go about solving a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I go about solving: $$ y'' = -e^{-y}$$

Am I supposed to do reduction of order?

Answer (score 5):

**A start:** Multiply both sides by $2y'$ and integrate.

Comment: Wait, how'd you get that? :o

Comment: Very standard thing to do in problems similar to this one, comes up in Physics problems. I imagine you will find the two integrations easy. Then solve explicitly for $y'$ (it would be nice if there were an initial condition). After that, you still have a DE to solve.

Comment: Uhhh where's it coming from though? I was given a similar hint by a friend. He said to just multiply it by y'. Where are these coming from? i.e. Is there a name for this procedure that I can look up?

Comment: @AlexWong It's generally called [integrating factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). And some forms of DEs have explicit formulas for the integrating factor that simplifies the problem. However, there is not always an explicit formula for it. Thus requiring you to make educated guesses as to its form.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rather longer way than what @Andre's noted. When our ODE is free of independent variable $x$, i.e.; $f(y,y',y'')=0$ then we can assume $y'=p$ and therefore by using the Chain rule we have $$y''=pp'=p\frac{dp}{dy}.$$ Hence $$f(y,y',y'')=0\to f(y,p,p')=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing a little from André's answer:

$$2\:y''y'=2\:y'e^{-y}$$ 
Integrating 
$$(y')^2=2\:e^{-y}+c$$ 
where $c$ is an appropriate constant, hence
$$y'=\pm\sqrt{2\:e^{-y}+c}$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2\:e^{-y}+c}}=\pm dx $$ ...

Comment: you are missing a minus sign (typo) in the RHS of the original statement. After that it all checks out.